# Is there a name for these similar sounding high-pitched voices?

Tags: hip-hop, sound, technique, dubstep

The voices in question can be found in these two choruses:

[I Feel Like Dying - Lil' Wayne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cykGnl1KvcM)

[Lonely - Akon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EEW-9NDM5k)

and also in this song starting at 0:13 seconds:

[First Of The Year - Skrillex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYYyMu3pzL4)

I hope I'm not crazy in thinking they are similar or could be categorized together. They have a high-pitched, sort of nasally sound to my ear. I've always enjoyed the sound and have a nostalgic attachment to them.

Answer (score 1):

The voice has been sped up in each case. This is often called the "chipmunk effect" after the 1958 recording by ["Alvin and the Chipmunks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvin_and_the_Chipmunks) where this was first commercially used.